# Cómo realizar correctamente un post con swift 3 - 4

Tags: json, ios, swift3, post

soy muy nueva en iOS y swift, estoy usando URLSession para hacer un post de user y password, el Json en response me da 200, sin embargo la respuesta del Json en sí siempre me da 0 y 0 en el value, cuando debería darme 1 y 1. 
Cabe mencionar que cuando trato de cambiar de " `as! [AnyObject]` a `[String:Any]` o `[String:String]` o `as! NSDictionary`" me crashea.

Lo que debería regresarme:

```
[{
    login = 1;
    datos = 1;
}]
```

Lo que me regresa:

```
[{
    login = 0;
    datos = 0;
}]
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias =)

```
Va código:

        func login(email: String, password: String, dist: String) {
        let url = URL(string: ApiService.share.URL_USER_LOGIN)
        var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        let bodyStr = "url=\(dist)&us=\(email)&password=\(password)"
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "content-type")
        request.httpBody = bodyStr.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request){data, response, error in
            guard error == nil && data != nil else {
                print("error")
                return
            }
            print(response as Any)

            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(String(describing: response))")
            }

            let jsonString = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! [AnyObject]
            print(jsonString!)

           }

        task.resume()
    }
```

Comment: Acabo de crear este repositorio que puede que te ayude a realizar request a servidores: https://github.com/scaverod/HTTP-Request-Swift-4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realmente lo que estás recibiendo es un array de diccionarios, por lo que castear a `[String: Any]` es normal que te crashee.

Prueba a castear a `[[String: Any]]`.

El por qué el servicio te devuelve los valores a 0, lo desconozco. Supongo que depende de como sea el servidor, lo que le estés enviando, etc... Has probado a enviarle lo mismo en Postman y te devuelve lo que tú esperas? Quizás hay algo que no estás construyendo bien

Comment: Primero una disculpa, intenté acceder de nuevo a mi cuenta pero no me lo permitía.... continuando con el tema, efectivamente, estaba recibiendo mal los datos, por un lado, en lugar de NSDictionary, debía cambiar a NSArray, abajo pondré el código y segundo, estaba poneindo mal los parámetros del bodyStr, por lo que me regresaba 0,0 
Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: El casteo que te proponía es precisamente un array, del tipo `Array` propio de swift, que a priori proporciona un mejor rendimiento que `NSArray`... Si la respuesta te ayudó, recuerda marcarla como válida y/o darle un upvote. Gracias! :)

Comment: No me deja agregar mi respuesta :C supongo que en otro hilo la pondré, tengo un problema con mis cuentas, están como duplicadas, pero sí, esa es la respuesta, gracias :D